# Regex to split text with hyphen points

Tags: python, regex

Suppose that we have the following string:

'We need the list fo the following products: - Abcd efgh ejklm - Efgh-ij sklrm, defasad - KLMNNOP/QRS dasfdssa eadsd'

I want a regex that return:

```
- Abcd efgh, ejklm
- Efgh-ij sklrm, defasad
- KLMNNOP/QRS dasfdssa eadsd
```

I write this one that works correctly but it cuts if we have a composed word.

```
import re
regx = '-\s[\w\s\/?,;!:#&@]*' # start with hyphen + space + mix of different characters
z = re.findall(regx, 'We need the list fo the following products: - Abcd - Efgh-ij - KLMNNOP/QRS')
for p in z:
    print(p)

- Abcd efgh, ejklm 
- Efgh
- KLMNNOP/QRS dasfdssa eadsd
```

Comment: `re.split(r'-\s+', text)`. See https://ideone.com/maUEHr. Remove the first item with `z.pop(0)`

Comment: TheFourthBird's post is below. Please add the comment below the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could repeat matching either the current character class, or only a hyphen followed by word characters

```
-\s(?:[\w\s/?,;!:#&@]+|-\w+)+
```

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/2RvFig/1) and a [Python demo](https://ideone.com/lBc9Dj).

If you don't want to match empty parts, you can change the quantifier for the character class to `+` to match 1 or more times.

Example

```
import re
regx = '-\s(?:[\w\s/?,;!:#&@]+|-\w+)+'
z = re.findall(regx, 'We need the list fo the following products: - Abcd efgh ejklm - Efgh-ij sklrm, defasad - KLMNNOP/QRS dasfdssa eadsd')
for p in z:
    print(p)
```

Output

```
- Abcd efgh ejklm 
- Efgh-ij sklrm, defasad 
- KLMNNOP/QRS dasfdssa eadsd
```

---

Or a bit broader match instead of only word characters:

```
-\s(?:[\w\s/?,;!:#&@]+|-[\w/?,;!:#&@]+)+
```

Comment: I want to detect just the point with max length `m`. I changed the regx as: `'-\s(?:[\w\s/?,;!:#&@]{1,%d}+|-[\w/?,;!:#&@]{1,%d})+'%{m, m}` but it seems not giving what I expect. You an try with this input: `"- absdwerr fafasasffasf fafafasfasf - bad - badb - aderrrquery-123 afasfsafas. faffasfasf adsdasdsak adshasdhsajk"`

Comment: @LearnToGrow I will check in a moment..

Comment: @LearnToGrow What do you want to match for this string: `- absdwerr fafasasffasf fafafasfasf - bad - badb - aderrrquery-123 afasfsafas. faffasfasf adsdasdsak adshasdhsajk`

Comment: I want to detect for example the points only with  3 words or let'say with 50 characters

Comment: @LearnToGrow If you want for example 1 word, or 1-2 words etc..`-\s(?:[\w/?,;!:#&@]+(?:-\w+)*\s*){1,2}` https://regex101.com/r/V8pqGU/1

Comment: If you want 1-50 characters you might use for example `-\s[\w/?,;!:#&@][\w\s/?,;!:#&@-]{0,49}` https://regex101.com/r/fVSQbG/1 But if you want specific matches, there is not really a single pattern that handles it all. Matching 50 characters is something different than matching 3 words. Also when there are rules in place like `-\w+` etc..